# How do I return a value of a function in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to return the result of an operation in a function but I can't, I'm very sure the error it's pretty clear but I can't see it and I think this is the normal structure to make a return on a function.

This is the code:

```
#coding=utf-8

def sum_function(num1, num2):

    result=num1+num2
    return result

num_1=int(input("Please type a number: "))
num_2=int(input("Please type another number: "))

sum_function(num_1, num_2)

print(result)
```

This is the script running:

```
Please type a number: 1
Please type another number: 2
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functions_practice.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(result)
NameError: name 'result' is not defined

shell returned 1
```

I've seen some videos and blogs but I still don't understand.

Comment: `result = sum_function(num_1, num_2)` and then print it. It will work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything you have is correct except for one small thing. When you define a function and want to get something back as a return value, you need to set a variable in your main code equal to the function call. Think of it like the function itself being a variable. For example:

```
function_result = sum_function(num1, num2)
```

when you declare this, whatever the value is you want to return from "sum_function(num1, num2)" will be passed into the new variable "function_result".

You are then able to use "function_result" to print, or manipulate however you like!
So, your solution would look like this:

```
def sum_function(num1, num2):

    result=num1+num2
    return result

num_1=int(input("Please type a number: "))
num_2=int(input("Please type another number: "))

function_result = sum_function(num_1, num_2)

print(function_result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that "result" is a local variable. You can only access it from within the `sum_function` function. If you want to print the result, try `print(sum_function(num1, num2))`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it worked, but if I wanted to make the way I made it in the file should I declare a global variable in the beginning of the script?, is there any way to make something similar but more efficient than leaving an empty variable until I fill it with something?

Answer (score 0):

The variable "result" is a local variable and it can be used just inside the function sum_function()